# Hibernate Java 8 time types support in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, module, version

I am using `java.time.Instant` with `Hibernate 5.1.0.Final`. It is serialised the proper way in underlaying database when I do not use `@Temporal` and include dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I include this module as a dependency to another one is serialized as BLOB.

I beleive the cause may be that both of modules have `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent, because they are actually seprate projects (not child-parent to each other). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Spring Boot` overrides properties defined in included modules. This happens **even when the properties are not defined explicitly**. Since `Spring Boot 1.3.3` uses `Hibernate 4.3.11.Final` by default, this version is applied to the whole project.

Thus, the solution is to set `hibernate.version` to `5.1.0.Final` in the including `pom.xml`.